# Dynamic templates and scope variables

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have some difficulties understanding the directive **attributes** vs **scope variables** passed in a directive.
I am working on a directive that dynamically loads the correct template depending on the *content type*. 
When I use `linker` function that use a **scope variable** to do the switch things work good.

If I use:

```
<mydirective ng-repeat="item in items" content="item" type="item.type"></mydirective>
```

I pass a `content` object containing the data for populating the template and inside this object I have a `type` property I use for selecting the template.
This is my directive definition (some code omitted):

```
//[...]
linker = function(scope, element, attrs){
    //templates is a service I use to retrieve the templates
    loaderPromise = templates.getTemplate(scope.content.type)
    promise = loaderPromise.success(function(html){
        element.html(html)
    }).then(function(response){
        element.replaceWith($compile(element.html())(scope))
    })
}

return {
    restrict : "E",
    replace: true,
    scope: {
        'content': "="
    },
    link : function(scope, element, attributes){
        linker(scope, element, attributes)
    }
    //[...]
}
```

Now, instead of this I wanted to pass a function to the 'templateUrl', like so:

```
return {
    restrict : "E",
    replace: true,
    scope: {
        'content': "="
    },
    templateUrl : function(element, attributes) {
      // I don't access to the scope but only to the attributes
      attributes.$observe(attributes.content.type, function(value){
        if(value) {
          // templates is a service 
          return templates.getTemplateUrl(value.type)
        }
      })
    }
    //[...]
}
```

Now,this **won't work** either I observe `attributes.content.type` or `attributes.type`. These attributes will always be `undefined`.

I have also tried to add the `type` as scope variable passed to the directive:

```
scope: {
         'content': "="
         'type': '='
        }
```

but it keeps on being `undefined`.

So basically I am really confused about the use of `attributes` vs using `variable scopes`

**EDIT:**

I guess it has something to do with ng-repeat. If I put a breakpoint on the line

```
attributes.$observe(attributes.content.type, function(value){
```

and I inspect the `attributes` value I get

```
$$element: jQuery.fn.init[1]
$attr: Object
content: "item"
ngRepeat: ""item in items"
```

so I guess `content` is not evaluated yet, that's why `attributes.content.type` is `undefined`. Wondering why..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is your `templates` service synchronous or asynchronous? [`templateUrl`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-templateurl-) function must return a string representing the Url, and wouldn't support returning a promise (I had to test it in Plunker just to be sure).

If it does return a string synchronously, then I'm not sure why `attributes.type === undefined`.

Something like the following works:

```
templateUrl : function(element, attributes) {
   return attributes.type;
}
```

I tried it with (somewhat modified version of) your code, and it works fine - here's the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/SpvTmj76LXoy2Znha29O).

As to your question, use `scope` for when you implement one-way (i.e. a directive reacts to the change in value) or two-way binding (i.e. a directive reacts and can change the value in the parent scope). Use attributes as an initialization values.

**EDIT:**
I understand the issue better now. There are a few things here:

**1** the values assigned to the type attribute should be interpolated (i.e. within the curly braces):

```
<mydirective ng-repeat="item in items" content="item.content" type="{{item.type}}"></mydirective>
```

because you need the interpolated string value, not the object (nor would you get the object, unless it was defined as `"=type"` in scope definition).

**2** You will, unfortunately, still have a problem within the `templateUrl` function, and this has nothing to do with `ng-repeat`. This is because these values are not yet interpolated in `templateUrl` function or in the `compile` functions, so you will get "{{item.type}}" as string. It would also not help to use the `$interpolate` service, since you don't have a proper scope yet.

One way to address this is to append and `$compile` `<div ng-include>` in the link function that points the template that you request:

```
link: function(scope, elem, attr){
    var template = attr.type || "template1";
    var templateUrl = template + ".html";
    elem.append("<div ng-include='\"" + templateUrl + "\"'></ng-include>");

    $compile(elem.contents())(scope);
},
```

Here's the complete [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/SpvTmj76LXoy2Znha29O).

Comment: My `templates` service is synchronous. I've updated the question, I guess this is more related to ng-repeat, but not 100% sure..

Comment: So basically your last solutions looks very similar to my first proposed solution (the only one working), isn't it?

Comment: Only, in the sense that it is in the link file, and not the templateUrl function. But now, you don't really need a template html retrieval service.